# General Exponential modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can anyone tell me how to solve this equation for lowest $x$

$$a^x \equiv n \mod m$$

other than trying every possible $x$ from $0$ to $m-1$ ($m$ is prime)?

Comment: It is a hard problem, discrete logarithm. As far as I know, one can do better than plain brute force, but no efficient general algorithm is known.

Comment: How much hard,can you suggest some heuristic etc.what if everything falls into lets say 32 bit range.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), and it's a hard problem. By hard, I mean that it's an NP (in the P$\neq$NP sense) problem.

So the short answer is that for anything of any reasonably small size, you should just do trial division.

For slightly larger ones, there are a variety of slightly-faster-but-still-slow algorithms, such as a variant of [Pollard's rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) algorithm for [factoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms), or the cutely titled [baby-step giant-step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) algorithm.