# Euclidean Algorithm with modular powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I have these two questions which go as:

1) Find $x \in \{0,1...16\}$ such that $x^{13}\equiv2\pmod{17}$

2) Find $x \in \{0,1...22\}$ such that $x^{13}\equiv3\pmod{23}$

I was wondering what the best way to approach these were, I was thinking using the Euclidean Algorithm?

This is what I have so far for 1):

We know hcf$((17-1),13)=1$, so $1=13s-16t$ for some s,t. But not sure how to go further? Maybe Fermat's Little Theroem but again not sure. Thank you!

Comment: In general, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515763/general-exponential-modular-equation), but here $17,23$ are primes, which makes things easier. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491103/solution-to-xn-a-pmod-p-where-p-is-a-prime) for example.

Comment: Yeh I have seen these, just can't get my head around them when trying to apply when to examples! Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) the first equation is equivalent to
$$x^{-3}\equiv2\mod{17}$$
$$2x^3\equiv1\mod{17}$$
$$x^3\equiv9\mod{17}$$
$$\therefore x\equiv-2\equiv15 \mod{17}$$

The second example seems like one can only solve with trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one what you can do is use  $$x^{13} \equiv3 \bmod 23$$
and by fermat's little theorem $$x^{22}\equiv 1 \bmod 23$$ Thus we get that $$x^4\equiv x^{22}x^4\equiv x^{26}\equiv3^2\equiv 9 \bmod23$$
cubing that we get that $$x^{12}\equiv16 \bmod23$$ and so you can see that $$x \equiv x^{13}x^{-12} \equiv 3*16^{-1} \bmod23$$ and with a little bit of trial and error you can find that $$16^{-1}\equiv13 \bmod23$$ Thus $$x\equiv 3*13\equiv 16 \bmod 23$$

Not entirely sure this isn't error free, but this general argument should lead to the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

For the second example,
$$
16^{13}\equiv 3 \bmod 23.
$$
Also here we can compute $16^{11}\equiv 1\bmod 23$ as descibed in the comments, so that $16^{13}\equiv 16^2\equiv 3\bmod 23$.